# ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda, ef-core-3.0

I have parent and childs nested tables.
Here is my model:

```
public class Categories
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoriesId { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public List<News> News { get; set; }
}

public class News
{
    [Key]
    public int NewsId { get; set; }
    public int CategoriesId { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    ...
    public List<Comments> Comments { get; set; }
    public Categories Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Comments
{
    [Key]
    public int CommentsId { get; set; }
    public int NewsId { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    ...
    public News News { get; set; }
}

public class NewsImages
{
    [Key]
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    public int NewsId { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public bool Cover { get; set;}
    ...
    public News News { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to send it from ViewComponent to View;

```
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        var group = _dbContext.Categories.Where(k => k.Order != 0).OrderBy(h => h.Order)
            .Select(c => new
            {
                C = c,
                N = c.News.OrderByDescending(n => n.Date).Take(5)
                .Select(r => new
                {
                    Y = r.Comments,
                    R = r.NewsImages.Where(rs => rs.Cover == true).FirstOrDefault()
                })
            });
        var model = group
            .Select(m => m.C);                     
      return View(await model.ToListAsync()) ;
    }
```

I am sure there are enough News records for every Category, But I get error :
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')
AspNetCore.Views_Shared_Components_IndexKategori_Default.ExecuteAsync() in Default.cshtml

**var bp = k.News.FirstOrDefault();**

if I use that code works fine :

```
var model = _dbContext.Categories
        .Include(h => h.News).ThenInclude(h => h.Comments)
        .Include(h => h.News).ThenInclude(h => h.NewsImages)
        .Where(h => h.Order != 0)
        .OrderBy(h => h.Order)
```

But when I use the code above, a few records appear for some categories, and some categories react as if there are no records.

Where am I making mistakes?
Thank you in advance for those who helped ..

Comment: Thank you for the reminder, Harald. I edited the code. There was a typo in transferring the code here. Can you reinterpret the code according to the last version?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have a big LINQ statement that throws an exception, and you can't find where the exception comes form, translate the LINQ into smaller steps, and `ToList()` every step.

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
{
    // Temp code: small steps, ToList after every step
    var a = dbContext.Categories.Where(category => category.Order != 0).ToList();
    var b = a.OrderBy(category => category.Order).ToList();
    var c = b.Select(category => new
    {
        Category = category,
        News = category.News.OrderByDescending(news => news.Date)
                            .Take(5)
                            .ToList();
    })
    .ToList();

    var d = c.Select(item => new
    {
        Category = item.Category,
        NewsItems = item.News.Select(news => new
        {
            Comments = news.Comments,
            Images = news.NewsImages.Where(newsImage => newsImage.Cover).ToList(),
        })
        .ToList(),
    })
    .ToList();

    var e = d.Select(item => new
    {
        Category = item.Category,
        NewsItems = item.NewsItems.Select(newsItem => new
        {
            Comments = newsItem.Comments,
            Images = images.FirstOrDefault();
        })
        .ToList(),
    })
    .ToList();

    // original code: 
    var group = _dbContext.Categories.Where...
}
```

I'm sure that your debugger will tell you which step is incorrect.